# get a value based on a Switch Statement

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible to get a value based on a switch statement in C#?

```
public int NumCandyBars (string candyBar)
{
    get {

        switch (candyBar)
        {
            case "twix":
                    { return _numTwix; }
            case "snickers":
                    return _numSnickers;
            case "kitkat":
                return _numKitKat;

            default: return 0;
        }                
    }
}
```

so the code above should return a value based on the type of string based to it.

Comment: the fact you want to do that screams "use polymorphism"!

Comment: Is `NumCandyBars` supposed to be a method or property?

Comment: remove the get keyword

Comment: it is suppose to be a method

Comment: Well then remove the `get` keyword

Comment: Did you try running your code yourself? This is easy to test. And once you remove the `get` you'll find your code works fine.

Comment: Ternary `? :` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public int NumCandyBars (string candyBar)
    {
        int retval = 0;
        switch (candyBar)
        {
            case "twix":
                retval = _numTwix;
                break;
            case "snickers":
                retval =_numSnickers;
                break;
            case "kitkat":
                retval = _numKitKat;
                break;
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum CandyBar
{
    twix,
    snickers,
    kitkat
}

 public int NumCandyBars (CandyBar candyBar)
        {    
                    switch (candyBar)
                    {
                        case CandyBar.twix:
                              return _numTwix;
                        case CandyBar.snickers:
                             return _numSnickers;
                        case CandyBar.kitkat:
                            return _numKitKat;

                        default: return 0;
                    }
        }
```

Don't necessarily need polymorphism, but select requires a constant value which Enum satisfies in this context.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are better off avoiding `switch` in favour of using a dictionary.

Like this:

```
public int NumCandyBars (string candyBar)
{
    var map = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        { "twix", _numTwix },
        { "snickers", _numSnickers },
        { "kitkat", _numKitKat },
    };

    return map.ContainsKey(candyBar) ? map[candyBar] : 0;
}
```

The advantage here is that `map` can be moved out as a field and then be programmatically modified at run-time.

```
private Dictionary<string, int> map = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    { "twix", _numTwix },
    { "snickers", _numSnickers },
    { "kitkat", _numKitKat },
};

public int NumCandyBars (string candyBar)
{
    return map.ContainsKey(candyBar) ? map[candyBar] : 0;
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    map["mars"] = 42;
}
```

Or, alternatively you can load the data from a config file, or pull it from an enum or database, and your `NumCandyBars` need not change.